# Are toolbars considered views?

Tags: android, toolbar, android-framelayout

I was working through [one of the Material Design tutorials](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-102-java/index.html#2) when I noticed [one of their Fragments](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android-codelabs/blob/102-complete/java/shrine/app/src/main/res/layout/shr_product_grid_fragment.xml) was using a FrameLayout with both a Toolbar *and* a RecyclerView. This struck be as odd considering that the [documentation for FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) has:

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to **display
>   a single item**. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to **hold a single
>   child view** ...

- Why would the tutorial be adding both a Toolbar *and* a RecyclerView to the FrameLayout if it was designed to only contain one view?
- Are toolbars themselves not considered views?
- The RecyclerView is the only object here explicitly with *view* in the name, but what is a Toolbar object if not also a view?

The FrameLayout documentation also has:

> You **can, however, add multiple children to a FrameLayout** and control
>   their position within the FrameLayout by assigning gravity to each
>   child, using the android:layout_gravity attribute. Child views are **drawn 
>   in a stack**, with the most recently added child on top.

- Why does the documentation contradict itself? It first (first quote) says that the FrameLayout is designed to hold a single view, then it later (second quote) says that multiple children can be added. Am I misunderstanding what a '*child*' is?
- Are the Toolbar and the RecyclerView then effectively stacked on top of each other?

I noticed that the RecyclerView's parent layout (a NestedScrollView) used `android:layout_marginTop="56dp"`, presumably to move its start below the end of the Toolbar (Indeed if this margin was set to 0dp then the Toolbar would obscure some of the RecyclerView). Thus, given the 'stacking' nature of FrameLayout children, I was expected the RecyclerView to be *on top of* the Toolbar if I removed this marginTop attribute from the RecyclerView (because the RecyclerView is added *after* the Toolbar in the xml design). This did not work, however; the Toolbar seemed to keep its prominent position at the 'top of the stack', so to speak.

- Is the FrameLayout in this example used more as a generic container where the children views are self managing their positions in the viewable area (considering the hard-coded use of `android:layout_marginTop="56dp"` in the NestedScrollView)?
- If the Toolbar *is* a view, is it implicitly given a weight such that it always remains at the top of the viewable stack of inflated views? One could argue this makes sense for the purposes of a Toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

FrameLayout can be used to add more than one child views..

> Are toolbars themselves not considered views?

All the UI Objects e.g. Toolbars, Buttons etc. extend the `View` object at the bottom where some may extend `ViewGroup` (ToolBar) in the hierarchy but at the botton, even the ViewGroup extends `View` object.

> Why does the documentation contradict itself? It first (first quote) says that the FrameLayout is designed to hold a single view, then it later (second quote) says that multiple children can be added. Am I misunderstanding what a 'child' is?

It doesn't, it doesn't say that the FrameLayout ***can only have one child***, it says it ***should have***,

Therefore, its said that FrameLayout can have multiple child.

Also `child views` are those views that are added in a `ViewGroup` i.e. as the name suggests, its a View which can hold a group of other Views.

> If the Toolbar is a view, is it implicitly given a weight such that it always remains at the top of the viewable stack of inflated views? One could argue this makes sense for the purposes of a Toolbar.

Ofcourse Toolbar is a View or you can say a ViewGroup,

It doesn't mean it stays on the top of the Viewable stack or inflated views..

You can always control where you want to show the Toolbar..

The reason why it is shown on the Top is that it is a general practice to show Title & other option menu's on the top of the View..